# Invalid query Locator

Tags: api, reporting, integration, bulk-api

I have a database scheduled connection in MS PowerQuery (native from the tool) to retrieve data from Salesforce. They are at a maximum 7 tables (objects) and summed up or not they overcome 20k records.

Salesforce has a limit that shows 2000 records at a time in the interface. Using this PowerQuery connection it doesn't limit, but Salesforce creates a query locator at each 2000 results to see where "it stopped" the last time. Each user can have 10 locators.

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=000323582&type=1

In this article it says that: Each locator, and associated results, is available for 2 days after the initial query executes.

So I can query 20.000 records for one user at each 2 days? I need to schedule Powerquery to run at a maximum 20k results by user? How could I overcome this limit, opening a new connection with other users, etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A query locator keeps track of a database cursor. In Salesforce, this locator is allowed to keep track of 50,000,000 records. To get all the results, the cursor should be utilized to retrieve all of the results. If you have seven queries across seven objects, you can keep track of up to 350,000,000 records. The client must retrieve the rest of the results in batches of up to 2,000. The ten locator limit simply means that if you execute 10 queries that each result in a locator, then an 11th query will immediately terminate the oldest query, resulting in an INVALID_QUERY_LOCATOR error if the client tries to continue.

> They are at a maximum 7 tables (objects) and summed up or not they overcome 20k records.

When using aggregate results, you're limited to 2,000 rows per query (not 2,000 records, just rows of output). When using a normal query, the limit is 50,000,000.

> Using this PowerQuery connection it doesn't limit, but Salesforce creates a query locator at each 2000 results to see where "it stopped" the last time.

No, there's just one locator per query, up to 50,000,000 records.

> So I can query 20.000 records for one user at each 2 days?

No, you can query hundreds of millions of records every day if you need to.

> I need to schedule Powerquery to run at a maximum 20k results by user?

No, the limit simply says that if there's ten active locators, then a query that produces an 11th locator will immediately terminate the oldest locator.

> How could I overcome this limit, opening a new connection with other users, etc?

In case it's not clear, this question is irrelevant, because you're not limited to just 20,000 records per user per two days.

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, but why am I getting the error? Any ideas?

Comment: @SalesforceAdministrator I don't know enough about PowerQuery to know why; my answer focuses on correcting any misunderstandings you may have. I suggest editing your question, or asking a new one, that more directly states the problem.